# How to manage the leverage browser caching for third party JS files?

Tags: performance, cache, cache-control, google-pagespeed

[image]

Is it possible to set and expiration date for the file `http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js`? And the other stuff down the list?

I want to bring up my score as high as possible. I'm using WordPress by the way.

Comment: That is 3rd party JS , I don't think that you can set expiration for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manage the cache leverage for third-party JavaScript files.

However, you can do it for the JS files that you serve. For this, put these lines in your *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>

# Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

For my WordPress site, it worked to pass the cache leverage step in Google PageSpeed (for my internal scripts).

Comment: `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"` this was the key to solving problem that occurred only in the JS files. In my code, it was set to `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, private, must-revalidate"`. Changing it to match your solution solved the problem. Thanks a ton!